# Is there a way to search/filter properties in Styles pane of Google Devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

On the Elements tab 'Find' functionality (cmd+F/ctrl+F) doesn't search through styles pane. Is there a way to type CSS property with HTML element selected and find it quickly in the Styles panel?

Answer (score 4):

Bottom right corner, light gray text says "Find in styles". Click there and enter your search.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, such functionality does not exist in current Chrome Dev Tools.
But its present in Opera Dragonfly and its very handy, so, probably Chrome will copy it, eventually (but no such feature request exists in [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3ACr-Platform-DevTools&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Iteration+ReleaseBlock+Cr+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=tiles) now).

Answer (score 2):

On the latest Chrome on Mac, I'm getting the filter at the top of the styles pane. I can't believe that I never noticed it given that I've needed it so many times!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using CTRL+Shif+F on the Elements tab